# unlink() in symfony: Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain null bytes I get an error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

the project I started with Symfony 6.3.6 was upgraded to 6.3.8. and then when I refresh any page it gives error occasionally. I couldn't find anything on the internet. I share the error below.

I'm not sure if the error is caused by the upgrade

> unlink(): Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain any null

> bytesSymfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Data objects are immutable.

console error:

```
admin:3742 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'className')
    at createTabs (admin:3742:64)
    at admin:3783:7
    at admin:3958:3
createTabs @ admin:3742
(anonymous) @ admin:3783
(anonymous) @ admin:3958
admin:250 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'className')
    at Object.createTabs (admin:250:36118)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (admin:250:48566)
createTabs @ admin:250
(anonymous) @ admin:250
```

Comment: Have you checked what `$filename` actually contains in such a case?

Comment: Evidently $filename contains something it shouldn't. Do some debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.
Actually I did the $`composer update` but it didn't update. When I use the composer recipes command

- I found that symfony/phpunit-bridge (update available) is not updated. and

> composer update symfony/phpunit-bridge

I updated it with the command and the problem is no longer there.